# Unable to add a project into jupyter through anaconda/ syntax error

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda, jupyter

I'm having a hard time importing a kernel into Jupyter notebook. The code I'm using in Anaconda is:

```
activate deeplearningproject

(deeplearningproject) C:\Users\asus>python -m ipykernel install --user --
name deeplearningproject --display-name "deeplearningproject"
```

And the output is:

File "C:\Users\asus\Anaconda2\envs\deeplearningproject\lib\runpy.py", line 163, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, _Error)
  File "C:\Users\asus\Anaconda2\envs\deeplearningproject\lib\runpy.py", line 111, in _get_module_details
    **import**(mod_name)  # Do not catch exceptions initializing package
  File "C:\Users\asus\Anaconda2\envs\deeplearningproject\lib\site-packages\ipykernel__init__.py", line 2, in 
    from .connect import *
  File "C:\Users\asus\Anaconda2\envs\deeplearningproject\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\connect.py", line 13, in 
    from IPython.core.profiledir import ProfileDir
  File "C:\Users\asus\Anaconda2\envs\deeplearningproject\lib\site-packages\IPython__init__.py", line 48, in 
    from .core.application import Application
  File "C:\Users\asus\Anaconda2\envs\deeplearningproject\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\application.py", line 25, in 
    from IPython.core import release, crashhandler
  File "C:\Users\asus\Anaconda2\envs\deeplearningproject\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\crashhandler.py", line 28, in 
    from IPython.core import ultratb
  File "C:\Users\asus\Anaconda2\envs\deeplearningproject\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 119, in 
    from IPython.core import debugger
  File "C:\Users\asus\Anaconda2\envs\deeplearningproject\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\debugger.py", line 37, in 
    from IPython.utils import PyColorize, ulinecache
  File "C:\Users\asus\Anaconda2\envs\deeplearningproject\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\ulinecache.py", line 11, in 
    from IPython.utils import openpy
  File "C:\Users\asus\Anaconda2\envs\deeplearningproject\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\openpy.py", line 9, in 
    import io
  File "io.py", line 1
    Python **3.4.3** (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:44:40) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Can anyone tell me why I get the Python 3.4.3 line in the end at all and is this why it is not running? I'm using Python 2.7 version. Is there a possibility that an old file from Python 3.4. that I had previously from IBM SPSS has stayed somewhere in the system files and is causing trouble?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check the system path, maybe python 3.4 is still there, or you have Anaconda for python 3?

Comment: @KacperWolkowski do you mean the environment variables? Yes, I removed everything from there, still the same error message.

Comment: Which version is reported when you run `python --version` on the command line?

Comment: @ToniVanhala it was Python 2.7.13

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, in case someone is running into the same mistake- for Windows 10, Python 2.7 creating a kernel in Jupyter through Anaconda works fine with:

```
ipython kernel install --user --name nameofyourproject
```